# Webview behaviour with Galaxy S loading webpage takes ages

Tags: android, performance, webview, galaxy

Can anyone help or has had the same problem with webviews and Galaxy S:

Opening a simple webpage (html, css, images) in a webview takes very, very long (40-50 seconds). Opening the same webpage within the browser take a tenth of a second.

The same app with the same webview and webpage on the same wlan works perfectly on any other given
 device - even on the Galaxy Tab it works great.

Just on the Galaxy S the webview takes ages to load the webpage. We have no idea what's going
 on here and we would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Is there anything interesting being posted in the device log? Something relating to networking or DNS, perhaps?

Comment: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well, seems to be a Galaxy S bug...

Answer (score 2):

I have a Galaxy S and the only real "bug" with it I know of is the RFS filesystem that slows anything doing storage I/O down to a crawl.

How are you loading the HTML? Do you just pass an http:// URL to the webview? If so, what URL? For a 100 bounty I'll be happy to help debug if you give this information... :)

In the meantime, try seeing if `webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(LOAD_NO_CACHE);` makes a difference. That will force it to not use the storage-based cache, which on a Galaxy S could indeed be mightily slow.

Comment: The URL is indeed just a simple http:// url and is loaded in the standard way: webView.loadUrl(url); I'm afraid I can't point you at the URL in question, but I'm sure it's an issue with the webview as the same site works perfectly in the Browser app on the Galaxy S. Will try the LOAD_NO_CACHE, thanks for the RFS hint

Comment: Hey @pheelicks, wondering if LOAD_NO_CACHE was of any help? If not, happy to think up new harebrained schemes for improving SGS performance.

Comment: Haven't been able to check yet! But would love to hear any other ideas that you have

Comment: I'll give LOAD_NO_CACHE a quick run through when I get home tonight. If it doesn't help, I'll do some performance analysis to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue here with a Galaxy S.
In LogCat I can't see anything suspicious.
I've tried pages without JavaScript, and:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority( RenderPriority.HIGH );
```

and:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

and different URLs - it's always slow. The more and the larger the
images on a  web page, the worse it gets.
Everything takes around 10 times as long as in the browser on the same device,
same network, same everything.

Comment: Reuben Scratton: that was brilliant, one line of code:          webview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE );
 changes everything. The webview behaves almost as fast as a real browser. Only loading of images appears to be slower.